# Empirical Mode Decomposition in Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

I want to move an analysis pipeline from Matlab to Python. I'm noticing a slight difference between the IMFs generated by the `emd` function in Matlab and those created by the `emd.sift.sift` function for Python. Specifically, I'm calling:

`imf = emd(signal,'SiftRelativeTolerance',0.1,'MaxNumIMF',4) %matlab`

`imf = emd.sift.sift(signal, sift_thresh=0.1, max_imfs=4) #python`

**What is the difference between the two functions?** Is there a difference in the default parameters that cause the IMFs to be slightly different?

[image]

[image]

signal =       0
-0.0009
-0.0036
-0.0080
-0.0141
-0.0218
-0.0309
-0.0413
-0.0528
-0.0652
-0.0783
-0.0920
-0.1059
-0.1198
-0.1336
-0.1469
-0.1596
-0.1713
-0.1819
-0.1912
-0.1989
-0.2050
-0.2092
-0.2116
-0.2121
-0.2114
-0.2107
-0.2101
-0.2095
-0.2091
-0.2089
-0.2090
-0.2093
-0.2100
-0.2110
-0.2122
-0.2135
-0.2147
-0.2156
-0.2157
-0.2147
-0.2122
-0.2077
-0.2006
-0.1905
-0.1769
-0.1596
-0.1383
-0.1131
-0.0842
-0.0521
-0.0177
0.0182
0.0542
0.0891
0.1215
0.1503
0.1742
0.1922
0.2038
0.2085
0.2063
0.1973
0.1822
0.1616
0.1367
0.1086
0.0785
0.0475
0.0168
-0.0127
-0.0402
-0.0655
-0.0882
-0.1085
-0.1265
-0.1427
-0.1575
-0.1711
-0.1837
-0.1952
-0.2053
-0.2133
-0.2183
-0.2191
-0.2142
-0.2022
-0.1817
-0.1513
-0.1101
-0.0575
0.0066
0.0814
0.1657
0.2578
0.3551
0.4549
0.5542
0.6496
0.7383
0.8173
0.8842
0.9370
0.9744
0.9955
1.0000
0.9882
0.9609
0.9190
0.8641
0.7978
0.7222
0.6394
0.5515
0.4611
0.3704
0.2820
0.1980
0.1206
0.0518
-0.0069
-0.0541
-0.0888
-0.1105
-0.1188
-0.1140
-0.0964
-0.0668
-0.0263
0.0236
0.0811
0.1442
0.2107
0.2782
0.3443
0.4067
0.4635
0.5128
0.5534
0.5844
0.6053
0.6162
0.6173
0.6093
0.5932
0.5700
0.5409
0.5070
0.4695
0.4295
0.3878
0.3454
0.3028
0.2606
0.2192
0.1789
0.1400
0.1026
0.0668
0.0329
0.0008
-0.0292
-0.0572
-0.0829
-0.1063
-0.1273
-0.1459
-0.1620
-0.1756
-0.1869
-0.1959
-0.2028
-0.2079
-0.2113
-0.2134
-0.2144
-0.2145
-0.2141
-0.2133
-0.2124
-0.2114
-0.2105
-0.2098
-0.2093
-0.2090
-0.2090
-0.2091
-0.2094
-0.2097
-0.2102
-0.2107
-0.2112
-0.2116
-0.2120
-0.2123
-0.2126
-0.2127
-0.2128
-0.2129
-0.2129
-0.2129
-0.2128
-0.2128
-0.2127
-0.2127
-0.2126
-0.2126
-0.2126
-0.2126
-0.2126
-0.2126
-0.2126
-0.2127
-0.2127
-0.2128
-0.2128
-0.2128
-0.2128
-0.2118
-0.2089
-0.2043
-0.1980
-0.1902
-0.1810
-0.1705
-0.1588
-0.1464
-0.1332
-0.1196
-0.1057
-0.0919
-0.0783
-0.0652
-0.0528
-0.0413
-0.0309
-0.0218
-0.0141
-0.0080
-0.0036
-0.0009
0

Comment: Best ask package author for example on github, if he doesn't help it will be hard to compare to Matlab hidden code. I just noticed you have different name of parameters, `SiftRelativeTolerance` vs `sift_thresh`

Comment: Thanks! If I skip the ```SiftRelativeTolerance``` and the ```sift_thresh``` parameters, I get a very small change in the IMFs generated Matlab and no difference in the IMFs generated by Python. Seems like they don't refer to the exactly the same stopping criterion as I had assumed. It doesn't solve the problem though. The Matlab output still looks different from the Python output. I will take your advice and contact the creator of the Python emd package.